# how to access map of custom objects in drools

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

I have following Drools rules file to which I send  map filled with Custom objects(NodeElement), map is a global variable because it has to be accessed by all the rules, have another global variable errors, which is populated when rule fails. i have used eval and was able to execute it successfully. After doing some research, found out that eval has some performance issues?

My questions are...

1) is performance issues negligible?

2) is using eval a good practice?

3) if i have to rewrite these rules? which is the best way to do it?

```
import java.util.Map;
import com.infodev.pojo.NodeElement;
import com.main.Errors;
import com.validation.DateValidation;

global java.util.Map map;
global com.main.Errors errors;


rule "Fixed / Floating ccy rule"

    when
        eval(!((NodeElement)map.get("FixedCurrency")).getValue().equals(((NodeElement)map.get("FloatingCurrency")).getValue()))
    then 
        errors.addError( "Currency", "Fixed currency should be same as Floating currency" );
end

rule "Payment / Settlement date rule"

    when
        eval(!(DateValidation.paymentDateValidation(((NodeElement)map.get("tradeDate")).getValue(),((NodeElement)map.get("paymentDate")).getValue())))

    then 
        errors.addError(map.get("paymentDate").toString(), "Payment date should be after trade date" );

end
```

And the map is:

```
Map<String, NodeElement> map = new HashMap<String, NodeElement>();
    map.put("FixedCurrency", new NodeElement("FixedCurrency", "USD"));
    map.put("FloatingCurrency", new NodeElement("FloatingCurrency", "UD"));
    map.put("tradeDate", new NodeElement("tradeDate", "2012-01-22"));
    map.put("paymentDate",new NodeElement("paymentDate", "2012-01-2"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the NodeElement can be identified using the same String you use as the key of your Map, why don't you directly insert the NodeElements into the session? By doing so, you can rewrite your rules like this:

```
rule "Fixed / Floating ccy rule"
when
    $n1: NodeElement( id == "FixedCurrency")
    $n2: NodeElement( id == "FloatingCurrency", value != $n1.value)
then
    errors.addError( "Currency", "Fixed currency should be same as Floating currency" );
end

rule "Payment / Settlement date rule"
when
    $n1: NodeElement( id == "tradeDate")
    $n2: NodeElement( id == "paymentDate", value != $n1.value)
    eval(!(DateValidation.paymentDateValidation($n1.value, $n2.value)))
then
    errors.addError($n2.value.toString(), "Payment date should be after trade date" );
end
```

I can't tell you if by re-writing your rules like this will increase your performance or not. That will depend on other things too. One thing you do get by this new approach is readability I think.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Why not go the full way and use `FixedCurrency`, `TradeDate` etc. as type names. This would *really* make it readable ;-)

Comment: Thanks it works.But just asking is there a better way to do it? can it be achieved even more efficiently?

Answer (score -1):

You don't have *rules*, you have if statements (disguised as rules) dealing with values in a Map object and other static object. (Why don't you run these checks after the additions to the map??)

There is no `eval` I can see in your rules.

If you need `eval`, you have to use `eval`, if you can avoid it, avoid it.

Comment: sorry those if's are actually eval. and not sure what your implying to when you say checks after additions to map, mean use if else instead of drools itself?... the above rules might be simple n could be solved using if-else but but my actual rules will be complex. can you point me in the right direction to how this could be done without using eval?

Comment: You aren't accessing any facts in working memory in these "rules", so what you have coded there is just an if statement. Yes, you could run these checks as Java if statements in Java code, right after those `map.put(...)` statements. -- As they are written now, you have to use `eval`. If they are more complex, they'll just be more complex if statements in the disguise of rules. And if they are all like this, just accessing a few static objects, you are missing the whole point of a production rule system and could stick with Java.

Comment: Map shown here is a static content but actually the map which is generated will be a  collection of key, value pairs from a xml document where key will be the xml tag and value is value of that tag. Want to run some business rules on this map to check if the xml document is a valid document?. this is my usecase. and when you say facts, mean java objects in working memory that is passed to drools right?. if it so then can't we use a map object instead of a java class object? and  its true that most of the rule will be just complex if statement but i think drools can help out in certain ways.

Comment: You could be heading into a mess of code. An XML tag serves to identify an arbitrary data object. If you have unmarshalled an XML document using something like JAXB or better, you have a nice hierarchy of objects, and it would usually be a pity to throw this away (unless you have a very flat structure of elements of the same kind). Google "Reasoning with XML Data Drools" and read Chapter 2.

Comment: Agree with you and yes we are looking at a very flat structure of elements, your paper "Reasoning with XML Data" was very informative and helped address few issues we had. Thank you.